# html- / styling of- tooltips in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tooltip

I'm trying to work out how Google adds images and styling to their tooltips that appear over markers in google maps.

An example of the desired behaviour can be seen here:

http://maps.google.es/maps?oe=utf-8&q=hotels+in+sydney

If you mouseover one of the hotel markers, you will see different styles (bold text, normal text), paragraphs or line breaks, and images for the star-rating of the hotel. As far as I can see from the docs, these tooltips are created by giving each marker a 'title' attribute... however, any HTML in this attribute is escaped; you might end up with a tooltip that looks like:

```
<p class="tooltip-text">This doesn't work!</p> <image src="/images/myimage.png" />
```

... which is not the desired outcome.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Here is link that shows you how to create a customized tooltip for Google Maps API V3: http://medelbou.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/creating-a-tooltip-for-google-maps-javascript-api-v3/
To see it in action, go here http://medelbou.com/demos/google-maps-tooltip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [these tools](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries). There's and infobox customization which pretty much replaces the default one but retains all it's properties. Hope it helps!

Comment: I guess you both answered my question... ie. you DO need to create your own overlay. But those libraries are pretty nice!